# How to Perform Large Deletes in the Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I am using Firebase realtime database. I want to delete a node which has huge records. So i can not delete with normal ways. When i try to delete with using rest, i can not do that. Default setting is "large". I have to set defaultWriteSizeLimit to "unlimited".

```
$firebase database:settings:set defaultWriteSizeLimit unlimited --instance <dbname>
```

When i execute above code, i receive an error message.

```
"Error: Unexpected error fetching configs at defaultWriteSizeLimit"
```

Below is firebase-debug.log:

```
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.317Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.318Z] Command:       /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js /Users/emrekhan/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase database:settings:set defaultWriteSizeLimit unlimited --instance dbname
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.318Z] CLI Version:   8.17.0
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.318Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.318Z] Node Version:  v12.18.1
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.319Z] Time:          Wed Dec 09 2020 12:24:13 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.319Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.319Z] 
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.322Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.323Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.324Z] [iam] checking project dbname for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasedatabase.instances.update"]
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.325Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.325Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 <request body omitted>
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.668Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"date":"Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:24:14 GMT","expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:13.682Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dbname:testIamPermissions  
 {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasedatabase.instances.update"]}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:14.782Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:24:15 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","server-timing":"gfet4t7; dur=768","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:14.783Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/dbname/locations/-/instances/dbname
 
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.499Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:24:16 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.501Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: []
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.501Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 <request body omitted>
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.766Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"date":"Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:24:16 GMT","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.780Z] >>> [apiv2][query] PUT https://dbname.firebaseio.com/.settings/defaultWriteSizeLimit.json [none]
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:15.780Z] >>> [apiv2][body] PUT https://dbname.firebaseio.com/.settings/defaultWriteSizeLimit.json "unlimited"
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:16.568Z] <<< [apiv2][status] PUT https://dbname.firebaseio.com/.settings/defaultWriteSizeLimit.json 400
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:16.568Z] <<< [apiv2][body] PUT https://dbname.firebaseio.com/.settings/defaultWriteSizeLimit.json {"error":"defaultWriteSizeLimit should be one of {\"large\", \"medium\", \"small\", \"unlimited\"}"}
[debug] [2020-12-09T09:24:16.907Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, defaultWriteSizeLimit should be one of {"large", "medium", "small", "unlimited"}
    at module.exports (/Users/emrekhan/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/emrekhan/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:191:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/emrekhan/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: Unexpected error fetching configs at defaultWriteSizeLimit
```

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm not sure what's going on there. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Have Firebase support resolve your issue? I am facing exactly the same problem with the same log.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem without a way out – @FrankvanPuffelen maybe you can help?

Comment: I was able to fix this problem for myself by patching `firebase-tools`: in `database/settings.js` I replaced line 23 with "return JSON.stringify(input)" and updated the setting successfully.

Comment: @MishaReyzlin it works, can you post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem for myself by patching `firebase-tools`: in `database/settings.js` I replaced line 23 with `return JSON.stringify(input)` and updated the setting successfully.

[This has also been reported to Firebase Tools Issues on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3228) and fixed and merged today in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/3217)

I assume we can expect a version bump on `firebase-tools` and then running

```
firebase database:settings:set defaultWriteSizeLimit unlimited
```

should work after updating to the latest version.